# Let $(R,M)$ be a local ring. Suppose that $R$ is noetherian and let $I,J \unlhd R$ such that $J \subseteq I$. Prove that the following are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $M$.

Suppose that $R$ is noetherian and let $I,J$ be ideals of $R$ such that $J \subseteq I$.

Consider the following statements:

1) Every minimal set of generators of $J$ can be extended to a minimal set of generators of $I$

2) $MI \cap J = MJ$

3) There exists $L \unlhd R$ such that $\frac{I/J}{L(I/J)}$ is a free $R/L$-module and $LI \cap J = LJ$

4) (minimal number of generators of $I$) = (minimal number of generators of $J$) + (minimal number of generators of $I/J$)

> I want to prove that $1) \Rightarrow 2)$ and $3) \Rightarrow 4)$.
>
> In fact, now I only want to prove that $3) \Rightarrow 4)$ due to @Rafael Holanda answer.

The idea is to prove that all these statements are equivalent, and in fact I proved $2) \Rightarrow 3)$ and $4) \Rightarrow 1)$.

More ideas: the sequences
$$0 \rightarrow \frac{J}{IL \cap J} \rightarrow \frac{I}{IL} \rightarrow \frac{I}{IL+J} \rightarrow 0$$
$$0 \rightarrow \frac{IL+J}{IL} \rightarrow I \otimes \frac{R}{L} \rightarrow \frac{I}{J} \otimes \frac{R}{L} \rightarrow 0$$
$$0 \rightarrow \frac{J}{IL \cap J} \rightarrow \frac{I}{IL} \rightarrow \frac{I/J}{L(I/J)} \rightarrow 0$$ are exact (remark that the 3rd one is using well-known isomorphisms).

I have no clue how to do this, can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a local ring. We denote by $\mu_R(M)$ the minimal number of generators of a finitely generated $R$-module. This turns out to be $\dim_{R/\mathfrak m}M/\mathfrak mM$, where $\mathfrak m$ denotes the maximal ideal of $R$. If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $R$, $\mathfrak a\subseteq\mathfrak m$, then $\mu_R(M)=\mu_{R/\mathfrak a}(M/\mathfrak aM)$ (why?).

1) $\Rightarrow$ 2) Let $x_1\dots,x_m$ be a minimal system of generators in $J$. This is equivalent to $\overline x_1,\dots,\overline x_m$ is an $R/\mathfrak m$-basis in $J/\mathfrak mJ$. Now define $\varphi:J/\mathfrak mJ\to I/\mathfrak mI$ by $\varphi(\overline a)=\widehat a$. Since there is $y_1,\dots,y_n$ in $I$ such that $x_1\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n$ is a minimal system of generators for $I$ we get that $\widehat x_1\dots,\widehat x_m,\widehat y_1,\dots,\widehat y_n$ is an $R/\mathfrak m$-basis in $I/\mathfrak mI$. This shows that $\varphi$ is injective (why?), so $\ker\varphi=(0)$, that is, $J\cap\mathfrak mI=\mathfrak mJ$.

2) $\Rightarrow$ 3) Set $L=\mathfrak m$.

3) $\Rightarrow$ 4) Let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ be a minimal system of generators in $J$. Let $y_1,\dots,y_n\in I$ be such that their classes form an $R/\mathfrak a$-basis in $I/(\mathfrak aI+J)=\dfrac{I/J}{\mathfrak a(I/J)}$. They are also a minimal system of generators for $I/J$ and then $x_1\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n$ is a system of generators for $I$. Let's show that this is minimal.

Since $\mathfrak aI\cap J=\mathfrak aJ$ we have a short exact sequence $$0\to J/\mathfrak aJ\to I/\mathfrak aI\to I/(\mathfrak aI+J)\to 0.$$ But $I/(\mathfrak aI+J)$ is a free $R/\mathfrak a$-module, so the sequence is split. Then $$\mu_{R/\mathfrak a}(I/\mathfrak aI)=\mu_{R/\mathfrak a}(J/\mathfrak aJ)+\mu_{R/\mathfrak a}(I/(\mathfrak aI+J)),$$ so $\mu_R(I)=\mu_R(J)+\mu_R(I/J)$, and we are done.

4) $\Rightarrow$ 1) Suppose $\mu(I)=\mu(J)+\mu(I/J)$ and let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ be a minimal system of generators for $J$ and $\overline y_1,\dots,\overline y_m$ a minimal system of generators for $I/J$. Then  $x_1\dots,x_m,y_1,\dots,y_n$ is a system of generators for $I$ and it is minimal since $\mu(I)=m+n$.

Comment: Ok, I understand the idea, but I have a lot of questions in 3 implies 1. i) Why is $\frac{I}{IL+J} = \frac{I/J}{L(I/J)}$? ii) Why $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ is a set of generators of $I/J$? iii) Do we have in general that $\mu(I \times J) = \mu(I) + \mu(J)$? iv) How can we conclude that $\mu_R(I) = \mu_R(J) + \mu_R(I/J)$ and how does it show the minimality of the set of generators of $I$? Thanks for answering (I know that this is somewhat boring) and sorry for asking this (maybe trivial) little questions

Comment: This turns to be longer than the answer. You asked a lot of basic things, but I'll try to answer them. 1. What is $L(I/J)$? I'd say that it is $(LI+J)/J$. 2. If the residue classes of $y_1,\dots,y_n$ generate the module $M/\mathfrak aM$, then $y_1,\dots,y_n$ generate $M$ by Nakayama. 3. $M/\mathfrak mM=M\otimes_RR/\mathfrak m$ and tensor product commutes with the direct sums and $\dim V_1\times V_2=\dim V_1+\dim V_2$ (vector spaces) 4. See 3.

Comment: Got it! One more question: you said that if $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $R$, then $\mathfrak a\subseteq\mathfrak m$ (because $\mathfrak{m}$ is the only maximal ideal of $R$ and any ideal must be contained in a maximal ideal [by Zorn's lemma]), so $\mu_R(M)=\mu_{R/\mathfrak a}(M/\mathfrak aM)$, and you put a ''(why?)''. How to prove this ''why'' part?

Comment: When I said $\mathfrak a\subset\mathfrak m$ I wanted to avoid $\mathfrak a=R$. Otherwise, it's obvious that we should have that containment. About the proof: notice that $R/\mathfrak a$ is also a local ring (its maximal ideal is $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak a$) and then use the characterization of the minimal number of generators as the dimension of a vector space. (Actually this remark is the key point of the proof, so try to be sure that you got it.)

Comment: Ok, then $\mu_{R/\mathfrak{a}}(\frac{M}{\mathfrak{a}M}) = dim_{\frac{R/\mathfrak{a}}{\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{a}}}(\frac{M/aM}{(m/a)(M/aM)}) = dim_{R/m}(\frac{M}{mM}) = \mu_R(M)$. nice

Answer (score 1):

$1)\Rightarrow 2)$

It is clear that $MJ\subseteq J$. Since $J\subseteq I$, $MJ\subseteq MI$. Therefore $MJ\subseteq MI\cap J$.
Let $\{r_{1},...,r_{j}\}$ be a minimal set of generators of $J$. Then there are $r_{j+1},...,r_{n}\in I$ such that $\{r_{1},...,r_{n}\}$ is a minimal set of generators of $I$. For all $x\in MI\cap J$ there are $m_{x}\in M, a_{x1},...,a_{xn}\in I$ and $b_{x1},...,b_{xj}\in J$ such that $$x=m_{x}(a_{x1}r_{1}+...+a_{xn}r_{n})=m_{x}a_{x1}r_{1}+...+m_{x}a_{xn}r_{n}$$ and $$x=b_{x1}r_{1}+...+b_{xj}r_{j},$$
so $$b_{x1}r_{1}+...+b_{xj}r_{j}=m_{x}a_{x1}r_{1}+...+m_{x}a_{xn}r_{n}.$$
Therefore $a_{x(j+1)}=...=a_{xn}=0$ and $x=m_{x}(a_{x1}r_{1}+...+a_{xj}r_{j})\in MJ$ (remember that $r_{i}\in J\Rightarrow a_{i}r_{i}\in J$). We prove that $MI\cap J=MJ$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea for $3) \Rightarrow 4)$?

Comment: None. I do not know.